# Is there a way to integrate testNG html reports directly to VersionOne?

Tags: selenium, testng, versionone

Our Agile Team uses VersionOne as the agile lifecycle management tool. 
Also, we use Selenium with TestNG for our automation testing of the web app using Eclipse IDE. 
Is there a way we can integrate the reports generated directly to VersionOne so that it updates the Test suite with the passed failed results?

Although we can create defects, assign defects, create Test suites etc, the direct integration of Selenium with VersionOne is missing. Is there a way we can achieve this?

Any suggestion would be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the VersionOne doesn't have a plug-in architecture (direct integration), you would have to write your own tool using the VersionOne Java SDK (or v1 Rest API) to sense the change in the assets that you are interested in tracking change. As far as integrating VersionOne reports, you cannot export and if you need the reports, you would have to write your own using the SDK. If you are looking to push data from your Selenium reports to update V1 test suites, once again, you can do this using the SDK.  My recommendations is get comfy with the VersionOne SDK.  If comes in Net and Java. Create a standalone Java app that can

1. Connect to VersionOne
2. Connect to Selenium
3. Read some data from Selenium and update some VersionOne test based on this read data.

This is one approach.  If you just want to do your integration with your Eclipse/Selenium environment then just add the V1 Java tar.  Here is a link to some blog posts that may give you an idea on [How to Build VersionOne Integrations](http://blogs.versionone.com/agile-development/author/abunch/).

Here is a link to the [VersionOne Development Library](http://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library).  You can get the basic documentation describing the various mechanisms for connection to VersionOne instances, reading and manipulating VersionOne assets.